# Azure Logic App Variable Query for getting Nested JSON Data

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Making a logic app to get the `alertId` from the below JSON data which is in nested form:

```
{
    "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
    "data": {
        "essentials": {
            "alertId": "hsbdfhsdvjsb",
            "alertRule": "sdvsdv",
            "severity": "Sev4",
            "signalType": "Activity Log",
            "monitorCondition": "Fired",
            "monitoringService": "Activity Log - Administrative",
            "alertTargetIDs": [
                "sdvsfdvdfsvbsfdvsdv"
            ],
            "configurationItems": [
                "sdvfsvsfvsf"
            ],
            "originAlertId": "100d184e-de66-4fb5-85f3-c7323152f2d7_631cda6004c25aa9b98faf499a4204ca",
            "firedDateTime": "2021-12-21T08:24:19.5575475Z",
            "description": "",
            "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
            "alertContextVersion": "1.0"
        },
        "alertContext": {
            "authorization": {
                "action": "Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action",
                "scope": "sdvsdvsdvsdfsdvd"
            },
            "channels": "Operation",
            "claims": "",
            "caller": "",
            "correlationId": "",
            "eventSource": "Administrative",
            "eventTimestamp": "2021-12-21T08:22:18.3314755+00:00",
            "httpRequest": "",
            "eventDataId": "100d184e-de66-4fb5-85f3-c7323152f2d7",
            "level": "Informational",
            "operationName": "",
            "operationId": "4800feb9-9145-4d02-a895-94bc1d636e0a",
            "properties": {
                "statusCode": "OK",
                "serviceRequestId": "4da88c4c-a108-4806-8cf3-86abc5bbfdfe",
                "eventCategory": "Administrative",
                "entity": "",
                "message": "Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action",
                "hierarchy": ""
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "subStatus": "OK",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2021-12-21T08:23:58.271818+00:00",
            "Activity Log Event Description": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest the possible way to find the `alertId` in the variable step of the azure logic app.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `Parse JSON` action from the `Data Operations` group.

Click the **Use sample payload to generate schema** option at the bottom of the action and load in your JSON.

Create an `Initialize Variable` and select the **alertId** field as the value to populate.

Images shown below ...

**Variable Initialization**

[image: IV]

**Result**

[image: Result]